# Cannot initialize ArrayAdaper with ArrayList : Java

Tags: java, android

```
String[][] tables = {
    {"2", "4", "6", "8", "10", "12", "14", "16", "18", "20"},
    {"3", "6", "9", "12", "15", "18", "21", "24", "27", "30"}
};

ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(tables[0]));
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, temp);
```

gives error:

> Cannot resolve constructor ...

how to fix this?

Comment: From where you try to initialize it?

Comment: Use Below code. 
String[][] tables = {
                {"2", "4", "6", "8", "10", "12", "14", "16", "18", "20"},
                {"3", "6", "9", "12", "15", "18", "21", "24", "27", "30"}
        };

        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tables[0]);

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman I've initialized it in last line

Comment: @ShohelRana Then it gives error _Cannot infer arguments (unable to resolve constructor)_

Comment: @ShivamJha where to use code fragment or activity?

Comment: Well, thanks for your concern, @user85421 , but the error was that I was initializing the ctor inside a function, so had to use `getApplicationContext()` instead of `this`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you try to initialize your `ArrayAdapter` outside of `Activity` context where `this` is not correct context to instantiate `ArrayAdapter`. Try to pass valid context instead of `this`

```
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, temp);
```

Comment: What do you mean by **Fragment** ?
I've initialized it in `onCreate()` method

Comment: Where do you use this code, Inside `Fragment` or `Activity`?

Comment: IN `onCreate()` inside `public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity`

Comment: In that case can you add `MainActivity`?

Comment: I've added it, please read above comment,

Comment: Let me replace `this` by `getApplicationContext()` and see what happens